# deleting only pattern from the lines of a file

Tags: shell

I just want to delete a pattern from a file using shell script. For example, given:

```
blah blah (100%) blah blah
```

I want to delete all occurrences of the pattern `(100%)`, even if it appears more than once on a line, and on all lines in the file where it does appear.

Comment: Is Perl available to you? This would be very simple using Perl. In any case, can you give a clearer example of your input and desired output please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed

```
echo "blah (100%) blah (100%)" | sed 's/(100%)//g'
blah  blah
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/(100%)//g' <yourfile>
```

Example:

```
[you@home]$ cat file.txt

blah blah (100%) blah blah
ah (100%) blah blah (100%)
blah blah (100%) blah

[you@home]$ sed -i 's/(100%)//g' file.txt

[you@home]$ cat file.txt

blah blah  blah blah
ah  blah blah
blah blah  blah
```

The `-i` option means modifies the file in place. If that is omitted, the result is printed to stdout and the file remains unchanged.

Comment: The GNU `sed -i` option is very useful, but not available except when using GNU `sed`.